# Vitest failed to resolve image import from nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt3

I am trying to render component using vitest and the component has image imported and its giving me error `Error: Failed to resolve import "~/assets/components-icons/warning_shield.svg" from "components/ActionCenter/ActionCenter.vue". Does the file exist?`

I tried to import the image directly and its working fine but it's not the best approach to do this what should I do? Can we mock the image if yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my environment, I was able to make it work by configuring aliases in vitest.config.ts as follows, changing `"~/assets/..."` in the template to `"@/assets/..."`. However, I don't understand why it doesn't work when using "~" even though I have set up aliases similarly.

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
      '~': fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
```